# Is this sequence with a square root in the denominator a Cauchy sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, cauchy-sequences

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uANI9.png)

For (c), I know that the definition of a Cauchy sequence is when the terms eventually become really close. I can see that the terms are becoming closer and closer to each other but does this sequence actually converge?

Thanks

Comment: In part b) you have almost finished proving that the sequence is not a Cauchy sequence. Think of $n$ as fixed, and $p$ getting very large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By b), you have $$\lvert a_{n+p}-a_n\rvert>\frac p{\sqrt{n+p}}\ge \frac p{\sqrt{2p}}=\sqrt{\dfrac p2},$$
which tends to $\infty$.